# android gallery animation with buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanna create android animation like shown on [this](http://arunkumarpd.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-gallery-imageview-example.html) example. Only one change I need here. I wanna create two button (Previous and Next). I want see next image for clicking next button, and previous- previous button. 
Is there a way to this or there is another examples? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In buttons `OnClickListener` increment the position of the image that u want to show

```
imageView.setImageResource(position);
```

[More](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29)

UPDATE

```
imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
```

you can get teh current position of the image using the methods available in example u gave.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but could you tell me more specificly, how could I get position on onClickListener?